# Xcode accidentally removed reference to a file

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally removed the reference to a .h file in xcode.

The file is actually a nuisance and needs to be deleted. I tried finding the physical location of the file and deleting through finder but it caused the build to fail. I have now restored it back to the physical location.

I need to undo the "remove reference" so I can then delete the file through XCode properly.

Thanks for the help

Comment: ... right click a folder / group and add the file back then

Comment: Is there a source file that does `#import "annoying.h"` still?  Please post the complete compiler error message.

Answer (score 3):

No worries.The file exist.
You need to add it again .

First click `⌥⌘A` and after add the missing file.